# HTML - Icons in buttons trouble

Tags: html, css

The icons inside my buttons are half outside of them for some reason even though there's definitely enough room inside for them. Why is this and how can I fix it? Also, with my css I have the buttons set to be blue but whenever they're disabled, the buttons are white. How can I have them not change their color when they're disabled? Thanks!

```css
tfoot,
thead {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

i {
  color: white;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

button {
  background-color: blue;
}

.footertext {
  float: right;
  padding-left: 10px;
  padding-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<td colspan="6">
  Requests:
  <button [disabled]="!isNextValid()" class="form-control" style="width: 50px; height: 25px; float: right;" (click)="nextEmployee()"><i class="fa fa-caret-right fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
  <label style="float: right;">{{selectedEmployee+1}} of {{empInfo.length}}</label>
  <button [disabled]="!isPreviousValid()" class="form-control" style="width: 50px; height: 25px; float: right;" (click)="previousEmployee()"><i class="fa fa-caret-left fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
</td>
```

Comment: Perhaps you could provide the generated HTML instead of the template markup. Since you're using Bootstrap I'd include that CSS as well. Also, Bootstrap has a grid system so (I'm assuming) you don't need to use a `table`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are using a fixed width on your button element. Instead of a fixed with, adjust the size using padding. This will allow your button to scale properly for its content. This will also keep the label and icon centered properly in the button.

Something like this:

```
<button [disabled]="!isNextValid()" class="form-control" style="padding: 15px 30px; float: right;" (click)="nextEmployee()"><i class="fa fa-caret-right fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
```

Comment: that just made them the entire length of the screen and also didn't fix the problem

Comment: Then chances are you have your buttons set to display block. Try setting the buttons to display:inline-block; instead.